# Oblivious that something

Tags: prepositions

The adjective **oblivious** is used with preposition **of/to**, but in the following sentence I don't understand its usage.

[**Oblivious that** an unconscious patient was still lying alone on a bed, staff of a State-run community healthcare centre in Uttar Pradesh’s Muzaffarnagar district allegedly shut its gates and left as their duty hours were over.](https://www.thehindu.com/news/national/other-states/unconscious-patient-stuck-inside-up-healthcare-centre-after-officials-lock-up-and-leave/article28108392.ece)

Also can **still** be used for past reference as used above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you understand *obvious of* and *oblivious to*, then you can consider the sentence to be an elided form of one of those:

> Oblivious ***[to the fact]*** that an unconscious patient was still lying alone on a bed . . .

---

The sentence would mean essentially the same thing without *still*, but it's being used to emphasize the fact that the man *continued* to lie on the bed (I assume unattended to and neglected) when the staff left.

*Still* is used as an adverb to modify *lying*, and *lying* is without a specific tense. It's the use of *was* in *was still lying* that puts it all in the past. *Still* has no bearing on that tense.